# Good code architecture for energy simulation problem?

Tags: python, simulation

## Problem & constraints

- I want to build a simulation of multiple entities producing and consuming energy over time
- entities can have multiple incoming and outgoing energy streams
- one step in the simulation should simulate a discrete time interval, e.g. 5 minutes
- some entities in the simulation should be controllable from the outside world
- examples of entities include batteries, pv arrays and production machines

## A first draft

My first naîve draft code goes like this:

```py
battery, machine, pv, grid = entities_from_data(...)

def simulation_step():
    """
    execute one simulation step
    """

    for time in day:

        energy_battery = battery.get_energy()
        energy_pv = pv.get_energy()

        # run machine
        energy_consumption = machine.run()

        # let battery decide what it does
        # in the next step
        battery.charge_or_discharge(energy_pv, energy_consumption)

        # either buy or sell energy
        energy_diff = energy_battery + energy_pv - energy_consumption
        grid.buy_or_sell(energy_diff)
```

I don't like it:

- difficult to test
- not dynamic / modular
- state mutations are scattered all over the code

## Possible architecture

One thing I thought of is creating a `Processor` base class which has, depending on its use, multiple input and output streams.

One could maybe then compose such `Processor`s by connecting inputs with outputs, respectively. This would result in a kind of graph representing the energy flow.

---

Is there any library / framework that is targeted at a similar problem?

Do you know of any architecture that is more suitable to tackling this problem in python?

Comment: You might find some inspiration from the environments here (https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/envs). They are all implementing an abstract environment gym.Env (https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/core.py). In your case, your simulation step would be an implementation of gym.Env.step. The fact that simulation_step is a function instead of a class method does not help unit testing not scalable designs

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using time steps, you might consider the discrete event modeling approach.  Time step modeling has been shown to introduce modeling artifacts which can affect the behavior of the system, while discrete event modeling adopts the philosophy that "things happen when they happen, not rounded to some arbitrary time step."  (See https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc11papers/218.pdf)

You can download a minimal discrete event scheduling engine implemented in Python at: https://github.com/PaulSanchez/SimpleKit-Python

The git repository has a PDF file which describes general modeling principles and discrete event modeling using event graph notation, and illustrates the approach with a queueing model implementation.